# Retrieving list of disk SKUs available

Tags: azure, storage, azure-cli, disk

I am trying to get a list of all available Storage SKUs that I can use during creation of VM. When I go to portal, I see following options.

[image]

Is there any Azure CLI command to retrieve this list? I have tried some combinations of az disk/storage without much luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the available Skus for the disks [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/disk?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-disk-attach-optional-parameters) under `sku` option.
Description for the each SKU can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/srp_sku_types).

If you want to retrieve them programmatically, you could use API call:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/skus?api-version=2021-04-01
```

as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/skus/list).

Comment: Thanks for your response. In the doc link there is following command 
az vm disk attach --disk $diskId --new --resource-group MyResourceGroup --size-gb 128 --sku Standard_LRS --vm-name MyVm , 
I am interested in  
--sku Standard_LRS 
part of this command. How can I get all possible values to use with --sku option? Is there any Azure CLI way of retrieving that list?

Comment: It's defined in the docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/disk?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-disk-attach-optional-parameters. 
Or you can use `az vm disk attach --help`